# What criteria distinguishes causality from retrocausality?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, causality

The brilliant philosopher David Hume remarked that if two events are always found to be correlated to each other with one event happening prior to the other, we call the earlier event the cause and the latter event the effect. However, it has been pointed out that two events can be correlated, with one happening after the other, but only because they both have the same common cause, and not because of any direct causation. It's not "post hoc, ergo propter hoc".

What stops me from defining a new verb "retrocause"? It works just like Hume's definition, but only in reverse. We note the presence of a broken egg is always correlated perfectly (or very very nearly so up to an exponential degree of accuracy. Loschmidt reversal, anyone?) with the existence of an unbroken egg in its past. So, we say broken eggs retrocause unbroken eggs. In the same manner, unbroken eggs retrocause hens laying eggs. And hens retrocause female chicks. And female chicks retrocause hatching eggs. And so on and so forth.

In delayed choice experiments, what stops us from saying the choice of apparatus settings retrocause the preferred basis of a quantum system in its past?

What distinguishes causality from retrocausality?

Comment: I removed the soft-question tag because the mods have a tendency to close questions tagged with that. I think this is a perfectly "hard" question about the definition of a physical concept.

Comment: This is why causality in this sense does not belong to physics, but to the useless parts of philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

It is 11 years later, and my answer is "retrocausing" your question!

I am surprised to see nobody has mentioned the causal calculus of I.J. Good, which provides a rigorous way to answer these kinds of questions. Good has an interesting probabilistic theory of causation built around information theory. The basic idea, paraphrased a bit, is that using the joint distribution of two Bernoulli random variables $X$ and $Y$, which Good treats as propositions, we can determine how "necessary" and how "sufficient" it is that $X$ be true for $Y$ to be true. These are two different relevant quantities of interest, and thus we get a more sophisticated theory than just saying the two "correlate" as you did.

The thing I am calling "necessity" is modeled by Good's "weight of evidence," and is given by $W(X \to Y) = \log \left(\frac{P(Y|X)}{P(Y|¬X)}\right)$, where I am using slightly different notation than Good. This measures necessity in the sense that it measures how much changing $X$'s state from true to false lowers the probability of $Y$ happening. With this metric, if $P(Y|¬X)$ is close to 0, and $P(Y|X)$ is comparatively higher, then the weight of evidence is extremely high, indicating that $X$ being true would be very much required for $Y$ to also be true. This does not mean that $X$ is sufficient - $P(Y|X)$ may be small as well, meaning $P(Y)$ is small in general - but if changing $X$ to 0 significantly lowers the probability of $Y$ almost to zero, then it can be viewed as one of the necessary factors that *must* be in place for $Y$ to happen, along with other factors that can raise the probability of $Y$.

The "sufficiency" is given by Good's causal Q metric, which is kind of like the "dual" of the weight of evidence: we define it as $Q(X \to Y) = W(¬X \to ¬Y) = \log\left(\frac{P(¬Y|¬X)}{P(¬Y|X)}\right)$, where I am again using slightly different notation than Good. This metric will be very high if $P(¬Y|X)$ is close to zero, and if $P(¬Y|¬X)$ is comparatively higher. In this situation, the idea is that we are not measuring necessity as much as sufficiency: if $X$ *does* happen, we want it to be very unlikely that $Y$ does not, compared to if $X$ does not happen. This does not mean that $X$ is necessary - we may have that $P(¬Y|¬X)$ is also low, meaning that the marginal $P(¬Y)$ is also low and thus $Y$ is very likely to occur in general. But if changing $X$ to 1 significantly decreases the probability of $Y$ *not* happening almost to zero -- meaning the probability $P(Y|X)$ is almost one -- then $X$ can be viewed as a "sufficient" factor for $Y$.

Good shows that these metrics are essentially unique following some basic axioms: they are independent of the marginal probabilities of $X$, for instance, among other things. He spends a lot of time deriving these things.

The main thing is that we have the identities:

$$
Q(X \to Y) = W(¬X \to ¬Y)\\
 = \log\left(\frac{P(¬Y|¬X)}{P(¬Y|X)}\right)\\
\,\\
W(X \to Y) = Q(¬X \to ¬Y)\\
 = \log\left(\frac{P(Y|X)}{P(Y|¬X)}\right)
$$

Which means that the "sufficiency" of $X$ to cause $Y$ is the same as the "necessity" of $¬X$ in causing $¬Y$. These are mathematically identical ideas. Similarly, the "necessity" of $X$ in causing $Y$ is the same as the "sufficiency" of $¬X$ to cause $¬Y$.

Given this lengthy explanation, your question has a real answer. You want to evaluate how much $Y$ "retrocauses" $X$. Thus you are interested in how necessary and sufficient $Y$ are in causing $X$. This gives the two different quantities:

$$
Q(Y \to X) = W(¬Y \to ¬X)\\
 = \log\left(\frac{P(¬X|¬Y)}{P(¬X|Y)}\right)\\
\\
W(Y \to X) = Q(¬Y \to ¬X)\\
 = \log(\left(\frac{P(X|Y)}{P(X|¬Y)}\right)
$$

These are simply two different quantities not equal to the aforementioned ones. And while Good has a long spiel about causation going only one direction in time, he does note that there isn't really any reason you can't look at these quantities as well, other than one's general philosophical beliefs about the nature of causality in physics. That is, since these quantities are formulated entirely in terms of the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, "time" isn't really part of the probabilistic framework involved here at all, so you can clearly just compute both causal quantities going in either direction.

Thus, using this framework, these are simply four different quantities we can measure. Given the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, regardless of when $X$ and $Y$ occur in time, we can compute the two information-theoretic quantities $W(X \to Y)$ and $Q(X \to Y)$, which represent the "necessity" and "sufficiency" of $X$ in causing $Y$, as well as the two additional quantities $W(Y \to X)$ and $Q(Y \to X)$, which if $Y$ is located in time after $X$, represent the necessity and sufficiency of $Y$ in "retrocausing" $X$. You can discard the last two if you want to conform to classical notions of causality; otherwise they simply exist as potentially useful quantities.

Let's use your example of a broken and unbroken egg. Suppose there is one chicken in the entire universe, and the propositions will be $X =$ "the chicken has laid an egg", and $Y =$ "the egg is broken". To measure the causal impact of laying the egg on breaking it, we care about the four probabilities:

- $P(Y|X) = ?$ - the probability of breaking an egg, given the chicken laying it
- $P(¬Y|X) = ?$ - the probability of not breaking an egg, given the chicken laying it
- $P(Y|¬X) = ~0$ - the probability of breaking an egg, given the chicken not laying it
- $P(¬Y|¬X) = ~1$ - the probability of not breaking an egg, given the chicken not laying it

Although we don't know the first two, we know enough to know that $W(X \to Y) = \log\left(\frac{P(Y|X)}{P(Y|¬X)}\right)$ will be very high because of the denominator being basically zero, indicating that laying an egg is an absolutely necessary cause of breaking it.

On the other hand, the sufficiency $Q(X \to Y) = \log\left(\frac{P(¬Y|¬X)}{P(¬Y|X)}\right)$ is variable; it could be large or rather small. The numerator will clearly be equal to one, as it is just the probability of not breaking an egg given there being no egg to begin with. So the entire expression depends entirely on the quantity $P(¬Y|X)$, the probability of not breaking an egg after it has been laid. We can also think of this as depending on $P(Y)$, the probability of eggs breaking in general. If this is very high, for some odd reason, then clearly laying an egg to begin with will be a sufficient enough cause for it to eventually break with high probability. If not, however, then laying an egg is not sufficient for it to break at all (although clearly necessary).

To look at the retrocausal inference, we compute the other four quantities:

- $P(X|Y) = ~1$ - the probability of the chicken having laid an egg, given that it has broken
- $P(¬X|Y) = ~0$ - the probability of the chicken not having laid an egg, given that it has broken
- $P(X|¬Y) = ?$ - the probability of the chicken having laid an egg, given that it has not broken
- $P(¬X|¬Y) = ?$ - the probability of the chicken not having laid an egg, given that it has not broken

This time we can see that the quantity $Q(Y \to X) = \log\left(\frac{P(¬X|¬Y)}{P(¬X|Y)}\right)$ is very high, meaning that a broken egg is very sufficient to "retrocause" its being laid.

On the other hand, the necessity $W(Y \to X) = \log\left(\frac{P(X|Y)}{P(X|¬Y)}\right)$ will again be variable, but in a different way from before. Again, the numerator will be one, being the probability, given that we have a broken egg, of the chicken having laid the egg to begin with. The entire expression will thus depend entirely on $P(X|¬Y)$, the probability of a chicken having laid an egg given that it has *not* broken. Put another way, we are primarily interested in the probability $P(X)$ of the chicken in laying eggs to begin with. If this is very high, then breaking the egg in the future is not a very necessary factor in retrocausing the egg being laid; eggs will be laid either way. If this is *not* high, though, and particularly if it is very low, then somewhat bizarrely, we are led to the mathematical result that breaking the egg in the future will be probably be necessary to retrocause that it be laid to begin with. After all, if the data say that "broken egg $\to$ laid egg" and "unbroken egg $\to$ non-laid egg", then it's as simple as that.

Summarizing this:

- Laying an egg is a *necessary* factor in causing it to break.
- Breaking an egg is a *sufficient* factor in "retrocausing" it to be laid.
- Interestingly, laying an egg may or may not be sufficient in causing it to break, depending entirely on how likely eggs are to break in general (particularly laid eggs).
- And most bizarrely of all, breaking an egg may or may not be necessary to retrocause the existence of the egg, depending on how likely eggs are to be laid to begin with (particularly ones that are unbroken in the future).

These results may be strange, but they really are what the information-theoretic formalism gets us. Clearly interesting, and beyond the realm of just looking at simple correlations!

Comment: "[Good] does note that there isn't really any reason you can't look at these quantities as well" can be extended with "isn't really any reason why you should look" either. That is, while the causal calculus of Good is rather interesting, it really isn't relevant in this particular question, thus somewhat answering your own question as to why it is not brought up. You can study all the properties of retrocausality and compare them with causality, and be none the wiser about why causality is distinguished from retrocausality.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion: I certainly think it's relevant!

Comment: It is nice to see some mathematical work in this, which is why when I reviewed your answer I liked it.

Comment: How does this compare with Judea Pearl's ideas?

Comment: What this tells us is that logic with finite sets is simply not enough to describe the physics of quantum fields with an infinite number of degrees of freedom. That is a rather trivial insight for so much effort, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Another brilliant philosopher, Immanuel Kant claimed that causality, like space and time, are not intrinsic properties of things-in-themselves, nature as it "really" is, as much as they are properties of the observing mind. It is the mind which determines causality, and the mind can be easily fooled.

Answer (score 1):

What distinguishes causality from retrocausality?  The laws of physics are pretty much time-symmetric so it seems the two should be not too different.  However, we all know that causality goes from past to future.  This is a question that many have worked on and none have fully resolved.  For an overview, there are a couple of pages on Wikipedia: [Arrow of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time) and [Entropy (arrow of time)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28arrow_of_time%29).  It seems the best answer so far is "it has something to do with entropy."

Answer (score 1):

Addressing delayed choice (focusing on quantum phenomena):
My simplified view is that setup of the apparatus (and other devices on the path) limits possible properties and paths of photons that may reach it, but, the photon (travelling @ c), makes the whole journey from emission to absorption (detection, collapse) in the very definition of an instant, even if we (incorrectly?) think of it as travelling for thousands of years.
It is then this subjective view of time that makes us prefix *retro-* to *cause*.

If this interpretation is accurate (mind the topic still confuses me), the term *cause* should be disused for quantum phenomena (replaced with *interaction*). For classical physics, *retrocause* is an oxymoron (use passive verb).

Answer (score 0):

A set of events are called causes for an effect if they're sufficient for that effect to exist. This doesn't imply that the existence of this effect is sufficient for the same set of causes to exist. So whereas causality is consistent with the world we're living in, your idea of retrocausality isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The central concept lies in the concept of "independent variables" and "dependent variables". Independent variables are those which can be "freely" varied, while the value of dependent variables are determined by those of the independent variables. What does "can be freely varied mean"? Can't we invert the roles of independent and dependent variables, invert the function, so to speak? And what do we mean by determine? Do we mean determine uniquely, or only determining a probability distribution? Do we need to include all the controlling factors to make it a unique determination? If only a probability distribution, what is the meaning of probability? Maybe what looks like probabilistic randomness is only pseudorandom deterministic or ignorance? Unless our model of causality is fully deterministic in the sense of a unique determination, what looks like a fully determined probability distribution can always be due to some other factors.

Monte Carlo simulations using pseudorandom generators. Do we say the pseudorandom numbers are independent variables?

Bell entangled particles. Measure a spin there, measure a spin here. In rest frame, there first, but still spacelike. Local Copenhagenist will tell you measurement *causes* the spin outcome, and the probability for its collapse. Nonlocal hidden variable guy says the apparent randomness of the measured spin here is really because we have not accounted for the value of the spin there. Once we do, what looks like randomness is fully determined by superluminal effects which in a boosted frame becomes retrosuperluminal effects. Another hidden variables guy tells you, all was determined causally and nonsuperluminally when the entangled pair was created in the same place, and the Stern-Gerlach orientation was also superdetermined. It appears the orientation is an independent variable which can be freely varied, and is one of the causes, but it's not *really*. Retrocausalists will tell you the orientation now retrocausally determines the spin basis during creation.

Your example. Maybe in future, 3D printing of female chicks become possible. Then, you can't say female chicks retrocause hatching eggs. Change that to female chicks and no advanced 3D printing technology retrocause hatching eggs? Qualifiers. Maybe the world is a stage and the apparent absence of 3D printers is only an illusion? Backstage, behind the scenes, a director 3D printed a female chick and planted it in your set when you weren't looking.

Problem of induction. Just because event A always led to event B in its future does not mean it will do so again the next time round.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to vary the "cause" "freely" while keeping all the other "controlling" degrees of freedom fixed, i.e. controlling for all the other factors, and such a variation leads to a change in the outcome of the "effect", that is causality. The problem lies in the choice of what to consider the other controlling degrees of freedom.

Suppose P,Q and R are three propositions taking on true/false values. Suppose R = P XOR Q. Pick Q as the controlling variable. Then, P causes R, but also, R causes P! Pick P as the controlling variable. Then, Q causes R and R causes Q. Now try picking R as the controlling variable. Do you now understand why people refer to the tangled wed of causality?

The existence of intelligent lifeforms, and the very long time it takes for such lifeforms to evolve retrocaused the fine-tuning of the cosmological constant up to $10^{-123}$, and also the need for structure formation which retrocaused slow roll inflation. The existence of carbon based lifeforms retrocaused the carbon nuclear resonance needed for stellar nucleosynthesis. The existence of heavy elements retrocaused the difference of the neutron mass from the sum of electron and proton masses needed for neutrinos to blow off the heavier elements in nova explosions.

Comment: Are you the same person as "Combative and confrontational", "Very difficult person", and perhaps dozens of other one-time posting identities?

Comment: And "Naive stupid boy" who posted 10 minutes later. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34713/1486

Comment: One reason that this is annoying is that you actually have something to say, but since it is scattered across a dozen identities, it's not possible to see how your thoughts connect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct definition for causality: something is considered a cause of a given event if for any predictor wanting to predict the outcome of that event, whether by reasoning, calculation, simulation, or some other means, that predictor has to include some sort of encoding of the cause, and the entire causal chain emanating from it right till the event, somewhere in the intermediate states of the predictor.

It might turn out there might not be any correlations between the cause and effect at all. For instance, the outcome of the effect might turn out to be the same whatever the cause is. But if the only way for any predictor to figure that fact out is to actually run many simulations with different values for the cause, and only then note the effect remains the same in each case, it is still safe to say there is a causal relation. The time ordering between the cause and effect does not show up in this definition.

Similarly, there is no need for the cause to be able to be freely varied. Even if the cause can only be the way it is and no other, if any predictor has to include the cause in order to predict, it is still a cause. For instance, suppose all proofs of a mathematical theorem requires invoking a certain crucial lemma. The truth of the lemma is a mathematical fact which can't be varied. Still, it is correct to remark the lemma caused the theorem to be true.

In order to predict that an egg will smash when it falls on the floor at a high enough speed, it isn't necessary to know that a hen laid it. So, that doesn't count as a cause. Similarly, to predict that an egg is going to fall doesn't require any knowledge that it will smash in the future either. To predict the behavior of a chick might require some knowledge of the biology and psychology of chicks, but it doesn't necessarily require any knowledge of the neuroanatomy of its brain, or the detailed anatomy of the chick.

If the best the predictor can do is to give a probability distribution for the event outcomes, that still always leaves room for hidden causes overlooked by the predictor under the guise of apparent randomness.

Comment: You say "The time ordering between the cause and effect does not show up in this definition." and yet you talk about a "predictor". By definition a predictor predicts the future, so your definition is about time ordering.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with most of the definitions of causality given here is according to them, if I have a certain memory or record that a certain event happened in this particular manner in my past, my memory of it retrocaused that event to be that way.

I would be interested to know if there is any definition of causality not explicitly mentioning time ordering which rules out this as an example of retrocausality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between causality and retro-causality (i.e. all causality is retro-causality and all retro-causality is causality).

For example: Causality can be understood like a wave-function of light - because light is a mechanism of causality. All mechanisms of causality are interacting all the time at every point of time. The wave function then collapses, to what is most probable, at any moment, upon interaction with matter and gravity. For each moment that matter and gravity dictate probability, it effects the wave function at more and more points of interaction.

This results in a temporal continuity where logic systems can exist and interact in an orderly fashion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple explanation for why retro-causation does not exist.

All broken eggs had pre-existing unbroken eggs but not all eggs become broken eggs. Therefore, we can deduce that an unbroken egg is required to become an unbroken egg. but a broken egg is not a requirement to have retro-caused an unbroken egg.

Now, you could argue that the unbroken eggs that never became broken simply are still waiting to become broken. We might need to wait infinite time to make this assertion complete.

However, your wording is inaccurate. The cause is some action that results in the effect. The unbroken egg is not the cause. It is simply a requirement for the cause to take place. i.e., a hammer hitting the unbroken egg would be the cause. The effect is that a previously unbroken egg becomes broken. So, the cause is the action of the hammer hitting the unbroken egg and the effect is that the previously unbroken egg is now a broken egg. Could you say that the broken egg caused the action of the hammer hitting the unbroken egg?

Now you are getting into the explanation above about Immanuel Kant. Causation is part of our experience of the sensory world based on space and time. This is an effort to reason our sensory experiences of phenomena. But these things will never be accurate representations of "reality". They will always be models that we use to interpret our experiences of reality based on how we think. Kant was far ahead of his time in understanding this concept. At the time of Kant, it was understood from Newtonian physics that space and time were universal concepts. But 100 years later, Einstein proposed that space and time were subjective to the observer and no longer intrinsically part of the universe.

So, the real issue with "retro-causation" is that our brains are not wired to think that way. We instinctively prefer to think of causation in the forward direction because that is how we experience the flow of time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any problem at all with your definition of retrocausality.  After all, it's just a definition...  So your first question is moot.

The difference between causality and retrocausality is the parameter time.  On the quantum scale we do use equations such that time moves backward to describe certain interactions.  However, on the larger scale these many interactions form a system where time moves forward (i.e. positive) not backward (negative).  Thus we tend to use causality, not retrocausality.

Comment: -1. "However, on the larger scale these many interactions form a system where time moves forward (i.e. positive) not backward (negative)." As far as I can tell, this is exactly what the questioner is asking and this response is a mindless regurgitation without any physical or mathematical content. If you could please elaborate and convince me otherwise I would be more than happy to remove my downvote (and possibly upvote instead!).

Comment: There isn't much to elaborate here.  As far as I know there is no theoretical proof that time has to move forward.  Instead, we simply know from experiment and observation of a large number of systems that this is in fact what happens.  Thus we say that time does have a direction, this itself being an assumption.  We could of course assume the opposite and say that time is reversed, but this simply doesn't predict the measurements we observe.

Comment: I don't mean to sound contrarian, and am absolutely sincere--if there is nothing to say, then why say it?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, I answered the question "what is the difference between causality and retrocausality"?  I don't know what you mean by "there is nothing to say"...  Even if there isn't a clean, mathematical, answer to this question doesn't mean it's not worthwhile to answer it.  I think the fact that we do observe time to move in one direction is significant.  I think that I did answer the OP's question by using that observation.

Comment: But, it seems to me like you want to rephrase the OP's question to be: "is there a mathematical proof that time moves in one direction?" (i.e. the universe is based on causality not retrocausality).  My answer to that question is that no such proof exists.  You can choose to believe that that answer is insignificant, but I think it is very significant indeed.  It is itself a proof that the current theories do not fully predict observed events without further assumptions.

Comment: But your comments *are* elaboration, and I agree with much of what you have said. I have more to say, which I might put into an answer. Since you have engaged in a healthy discussion and have defended your answer, I would be more than happy to remove my downvote. However, it seems that the SE software won't allow me to change my vote unless you edit your answer.